# Why is the Hotel Search API returning me an empty response?

Tags: amadeus

I am trying to access the Hotel Search API through the API Explorer (https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/hotel/api-doc/hotel-search/api-reference/v/3.0). I can use all the other APIs without issue.

A fairly simple request (using the default parameters except the checkin date, because that's in the past now), is returning an empty response.

[My entries in API Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEmGw.png)

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v3/shopping/hotel-offers?hotelIds=MCLONGHM&adults=1&checkInDate=2023-01-22&roomQuantity=1&paymentPolicy=NONE&bestRateOnly=true

[Empty response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRb8w.png)

I've tried with other combinations of hotel codes, dates, etc. And everything seems to be returning an empty response. I've also tried manually generating the access token and calling via Postman. It doesn't seem to be an issue with connection or server availability (since the status code is 200), I'm just seeing an empty response.

I'm not sure if this is a remote issue, or if I'm just doing something silly and missing something obvious.

Comment: Can you provides more detail about Hotel? CityCode or  GeoLocation(latitude&longitude). MCLONGHM (hotelid) can't find it.

Comment: I can reproduced any hotelids for LAS, this API return "data": []. It seems no data response even if 200 OK status.

Comment: @BenchVue That's the default entry when I open the API Explorer. I've tried for other hotels, for example, SIYYZ692 (Sheraton Gateway Toronto Airport) is the one that I use to test other functions, and that's also returning an empty response.

Comment: Yes, I confirmed CityCode (YYZ) makes multiple Hodel IDs, all hotel's offer search return [] too. I think this function not working or charged service only.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are using the [test environment](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/apis-docs/guides/test-environment-data-collection-746). A working example of an API call that returns data in test is

`GET https://test.api.amadeus.com/v3/shopping/hotel-offers?hotelIds=MCLONGHM&checkInDate=2023-01-27`

For access to full data you would have to move to production.